# R Speed a loop on rows with values a_i and b_i in which we select the row which a = b_i and b = a_i

Tags: r

I have a big dataframe (250000 lines)."Row" and "Col" are column names.
Given a line with the values Row = a, Col = b, I want to find the corresponding line with values Row = b, Col = a, and store a value (column "normalised_weight") in an empty column (column "weight_ji").
For now,my code works but takes forever.
Is there a more efficient way to code it ?

Here is the code I have for now :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    a <- data[i,]$Row
    b <- data[i,]$Col
    data[i,]$weight_ji <- data[which(data$Col==a&data$Row==b),]$normalised_weight
  }
```

EDIT

I tried all three answers, they all work, so I compared the execution time like following :

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    a = 1:10,
    b = 10:1,
    normalizeweight = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T) / 100
  )

start <- Sys.time()
result <- merge(data, data, by.x = c('a', 'b'), by.y = c('b', 'a'))
time1 <- Sys.time()-start


start <- Sys.time()
result <- data %>%
  left_join(data, data, by = c("a" = "b", "b" = "a"))
time2 <- Sys.time()-start

start <- Sys.time()
result <- within(
  data,
  weight_ji <- normalizeweight[match(b, a)]
)
time3 <- Sys.time()-start
```

It seems the fastest way is the third solution.

BUT if the dataframe is kind of irregular, like :

```
data <- 
  data.frame(
    a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4),
    b = c(1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4),
    normalizeweight = sample(1:100, 7, replace = T) / 100
  )
```

Then the third solution does not work anymore.

An update of the third solution for this case (duplicates) is :

```
start <- Sys.time()
result <- within(
  data,
  weight_ji <- normalizeweight[order(a)][order(b, a)]
)
time4 <- Sys.time()-start
```

This solution is still the fastest in the case of duplicates.

For the merge() solution :

In order to avoid having thousands of ".x" and ".y" colums (in my dataset I have much more than 3 columns), I did this :

```
data <- merge(data, data[, c("Col", "Row", "normalised_weight")], by.x = c('Row', 'Col'), by.y = c('Col', 'Row'))%>%
    dplyr::rename(normalised_weight=normalised_weight.x,  weight_ji=normalised_weight.y)
```

Thank you so much for your help, it is heartwarming !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `match` for indexing the rows, e.g.,

```
within(
  data,
  weight_ji <- normalizeweight[match(Col, Row)]
)
```

or

```
within(
  data,
  weight_ji <- normalizeweight[order(a)][order(b, a)]
)
```

Comment: Thank you !! Your answer works and I think is the fasted. I edited my question with it :)

Comment: I just ran tests with less regular data and it does not work anymore : for instance with `data <- 
  data.frame(
    a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4),
    b = c(1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4),
    normalizeweight = sample(1:100, 7, replace = T) / 100
  )`

Comment: @Camchou I updated my solution, you can try the second approach if you have duplicates

Comment: it works and is still a little faster than with merge(), well done !! I will edit my post accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a self-join with your data itself.

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(Row = 1:5, Col = 5:1, normalizeweight = rnorm(5))
result <- merge(data, data, by.x = c('Row', 'Col'), by.y = c('Col', 'Row'))
result

#  Row Col normalizeweight.x normalizeweight.y
#1   1   5           -0.5605            0.1293
#2   2   4           -0.2302            0.0705
#3   3   3            1.5587            1.5587
#4   4   2            0.0705           -0.2302
#5   5   1            0.1293           -0.5605
```

where `normalizeweight.x` is the original `normalizeweight` column and `normalizeweight.y` is `weight_ji` column.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer works and I edited my question with it :)

Answer (score 1):

It is faster with a `left_join`. Please make sure you do not have duplicate observations.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234) 

data <- 
  data.frame(
    a = 1:10,
    b = 10:1,
    normalizeweight = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T) / 100
  )

data %>%
 left_join(data, data, by = c("a" = "b", "b" = "a"))
```

Note: Any `inner_join` like command will remove rows where a pair `(a,b)` does not have a matching `(b,a)`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Your answer works, so I edited my question with it :)